# How to retrieve a specific Firebase document id from a query that returns just one document using @angular/fire

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7, angularfire2

I am trying to update a sub-collection inside the most recent entry in a Cloud Firestore. The sub-collection is called "timer" and it is inside of a collection called "matches1". Currently I am passing "documentid" which holds the document. But this is causing errors. I would like to just do one query and be able to listen to the latest changes inside that sub-collection.

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class myService {
    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore){}

getFirestoreData(documentid){

return this.db.collection('matches1', ref => ref.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(1)).doc(documentid).collection('timer').doc('timer').snapshotChanges();

  }
}
```

I am don't want to have to pass the document, I just want access to the sub-collection so I can subscribe and listen for snapshotChanges()

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: this code is not getting an error. Its just I don't want to pass documentid. I should just have access to it since I am querying 1 document.